# How to read an external YAML file on the internet and output to XML

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, yaml

I need to be able to make a Ruby application (no Rails, if possible) that opens an external YAML file that has over 104K lines of code in it, reads from it and filters out the following three things:

```
!ruby/object:EvtEvent
!ruby/object:NwsPost
!ruby/object:Asset
```

and then outputs these things to an XML file that would have to be built by the Ruby program.

1. I am unclear *how* to start with setting this up, as I am only a junior-level developer with one year's experience.
2. Although I found something on Stack Overflow that shows this snippet of a code example on using Nokogiri, I don't know exactly where to put this code which I would have to modify for my situation:

   ```
   require 'yaml'
   require 'nokogiri'

   yaml = "getOrderDetails:
   Id: '114'
   Name: 'XYZ'"
   doc = YAML.load yaml

   output = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
   xml.product{
   xml.id doc["getOrderDetails"]["Id"]
   xml.name doc["getOrderDetails"]["Name"]
   }
   end
   puts output.to_xml
   #=> <?xml version="1.0"?>
   #=> <product>
   #=> <id>114</id>
   #=> <name>XYZ</name>
   #=> </product>
   ```
3. How would I code the init.rb file to launch a Ruby program that would open the YAML file in question, read from it, and then output it to XML?
4. What other Ruby files would I need to put in my lib folder for such a Ruby program to handle this task?

Comment: Yeah Tin Man, EVERY tutorial and guide available to me. I've been struggling with this for awhile now as a jr dev who doesn't have the privilege of having a mentor, or the privilege of having money to afford expensive bootcamps and courses.

Answer (score -1):

1. The code can go wherever it's convenient. Ruby has no real expectation of file locations; You just run them. Your development team probably has guidelines, so you need to talk to them.
2. "init.rb" is a non-descriptive name for a file. Try to use something more indicative of the purpose of the script.
3. Reading a remove file for this purpose is easy with [OpenURI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/index.html):

   ```
   foo = open('http://domain.com/path/to/file.yaml').read
   ```

   will return the contents of the file and store them in the variable `foo`.
4. The contents of the YAML can be parsed easily using:

   ```
   yaml = YAML.load(foo)
   ```

   At that point `haml` will contain an array or a hash, which can then be accessed as normal.

   What's more interesting is that, once OpenURI is loaded, it will patch the `open` method, which *should* make it possible to do something like:

   ```
   require 'open-uri'
   yaml = YAML.load_file('http://domain.com/path/to/file.yaml')
   ```

   YAML has to open a file to load from the disk, which is what `load_file` normally does, and after OpenURI does its magic the YAML class should have inherited that magic. I haven't tested that but it should work.
5. Nokogiri's [Builder](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Builder) interface is probably a good way to go.

Comment: Do I need to make a Gemfile like that which is generated automatically in a Rails app to do this, Tin Man?